# How to delete a world folder in Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I found many ways on the internet to delete a world folder, but nothing worked.
Does anyone knows how to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got your problem! After the world unloads the server doesnt know it anymore.

```java
all.teleport(Bukkit.getWorld(lobbyWorld).getSpawnLocation());

if (Bukkit.getWorld(worldName) == null) return;

File folder = Bukkit.getWorld(worldName).getWorldFolder();
Bukkit.unloadWorld(Bukkit.getWorld(worldName), false);

folder.delete();

World world = WorldCreator.name(worldName).environment(World.Environment.NORMAL).type(WorldType.NORMAL).createWorld();
```

Comment: Do not write multiple answers. If the first answer isn't good, then EDIT it, and make sure it contains all relevant information. Don't just abandon your old content when it doesn't work! So please edit one of your answers to have the complete helpful content, and delete the other one.

Comment: @LeviHeßmann I think the same world is always regenerating... Do know why?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the world folder you should use:       `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(folder);`

because `folder.delete();` does not delete not empty directories.